# Badge suggestion

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

On one of the stackexchanges I use, I have noticed a few users that don't upvote or rarely at all whereas they downvote like it is going out of style. To be that pessimistic all time, must be a challenge so why not reward them with a badge?

My suggestion is:

1. negative nancy (bronze)--atleast 250 downvotes with at most only 250 upvotes and the badge scales linearly,
2. misery loves company (silver)--atleast 500 downvotes with at most only 250 upvotes (again scales), and
3. the grinch (gold)--atleast 1000 downvotes with at most only 250 upvotes (again scales).

I know this badge isn't a positive badge but there are other badges that aren't necessarily positive either.

Comment: @random I think my tiers are better the linked question though.

Answer (score 3):

I can see several problems with this idea:

1. Badge hunters - this would potentially encourage further down voting so some can get the badges.
2. You are missing the point that most of the downvotes are more than likely for questions and/or answers that do not meet the community agreed standards, are off topic etc.
3. Downvotes do not necessarily mean pessimism at all, in fact, it is a positive in that community is upholding the standards mentioned in point 2..

Comment: One of the people that gave me the idea hasn't been around long enough to encounter that many bad post to warrant the amount they have. I do understand what you are saying though. I was actually hoping this would have the reverse effect by making people not want the badge. Plus, it would be funny badge. A little levity is good.